# In Perl: Is there a way to know the name of a variable in a list?

Tags: perl, reference, scalar

Is there a way to know the name of a variable in this situation without using symbolic links?

```
use strict;
...
for ($var1, $var2, $var3)
{
   die "NAME_OF_VAR is not defined" if !defined $_;
}
```

The output if a var is not defined:

"var[123] is not defined at ..."

Comment: I doubt it (what would it mean if you could do it and the list was `for ($var1, undef, $var2) {...`). But there have been many times when I didn't think something could be done in Perl and I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get a fatal warning of an undefined variable:

```
my ($var1, $var2, $var3) = 1..2;

{
    use warnings FATAL => 'all';
    my $test = "$var1 $var2 $var3";
}
```

**Output:**

The script dies when an error occurs within the block above. In this case:

```
Use of uninitialized value $var3 in concatenation (.) or string at ...
```

I chose the concatenation as a test of definedness, but it could be any operation that causes a warning when undefined variables are used.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($var1, $var2, $var3) = 1..2;
for( qw($var1 $var2 $var3) ) { print "$_ is undefined\n" if !defined eval($_) }
```

The `my` line's borrowed from TLP's example, and has the following output:

```
$var3 is undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

[PadWalker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PadWalker) is the answer to unraveling aliases.  However, in almost any situation where PadWalker is the answer, it might be the answer to the wrong question.  It's one of those modules that one uses either for debugging, or for finding a way out after painting ones self into a corner.  If it's being used as an exit from bad design, maybe reconsidering the design is a better option.  In your case, the answer is probably the one that was already mentioned: elevating a warning to failure.

Nevertheless, the module exists, works, and is fun to play with.

**Since the question specifically asked about unraveling or inspecting aliases**, here are two examples where PadWalker is able to cut through the alias back to the original variable:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


use PadWalker qw( var_name );


my( $var1, $var2, $var3 ) = ( undef, undef, undef );


for ($var1, $var2, $var3) {
    warn var_name( 0, \$_ ) . ' is not defined in "for" loop'
        if !defined $_;
}


sub foo {
    warn var_name( 1, \$_[0] ) . ' is not defined in sub foo()'
        if !defined $_[0];
}

foo( $var1 );
```

The output that yields will be something like this:

```
$var1 is not defined in "for" loop at mytest.pl line 13.
$var2 is not defined in "for" loop at mytest.pl line 13.
$var3 is not defined in "for" loop at mytest.pl line 13.
$var1 is not defined in sub foo() at mytest.pl line 19.
```

Notice how it is necessary to specify `var_name( 0, ...` inside the `for` loop, whereas inside the subroutine we need to walk back one additional level by using `varname( 1, ...`.

Also possibly of interest is that `given/when` statements don't use aliasing although they give the appearance of doing so.  Consequently, PadWalker isn't able to trace back to the variable specified in `given(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have said it yourself, you need symbolic refs. Remember, these are not evil, they just aren't *usually* what you want. In this specific case, you are doing a kind of meta-programming, you care about the name of a variable. Therefore you can do this.

```
use strict;
...
for (qw/var1 var2 var3/)
{
   no strict 'refs';
   die "$_ is not defined" if !defined ${$_};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the PadWalker module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use PadWalker qw(var_name);

my $foo = 123;
print var_name(0, \$foo), "\n"; # prints "$foo"
```

PadWalker is not installed by default so you will need to install it using the cpan command line tool on your system.

Of course, PadWalker is crazy and is probably not the best way to do whatever you are trying to do, but it is certainly fun to fool around with once in a while.